# While installing Andorid studio AVD An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image: Read timed out

Tags: android

Error Android Studio

Packages to install:

- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86)

Preparing "Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision: 10)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-30_r10.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image: Read timed out.
"Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision: 10)" failed.
Failed packages:

- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86)

Answer (score 0):

[image: error when install AVD in Android studio]

### error when install AVD in Android studio

I did a lot of research on this topic until I came to the following conclusion and solved my problem

**This error occurs when your system is unable to access Google's servers.**

Unfortunately, Google has banned some countries and even with VPn it can not be bypassed, you have to use DNS. Set these Dns in your Windows: `178.22.122.100` & `185.51.200.2` .

this link help you to change or set Dns in Windows (This is very simple for programmers):
[change dns in windows](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10)

This is a very disgusting thing by Google that limits programmers because of their nationality